# Installing node.js on Windows cygwin error

Tags: python, node.js, g++, cygwin, configure

I tried to install node.js by following instructions here: 
https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Building-node.js-on-Cygwin-(Windows)

I got these errors after running ./configure:

```
$ ./configure
Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++
  2 [main] python 6768 C:\cygwin\bin\python.exe: *** fatal error - unable to remap \\?\C:\cygwin\lib\python2.6\lib-dynload\time.dll to same address as parent: 0x3A0000 != 0x3D0000
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
002891E8  6102796B  (002891E8, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
002894D8  6102796B  (6117EC60, 00008000, 00000000, 61180977)
0028A508  61004F1B  (611A7FAC, 61249144, 003A0000, 003D0000)
End of stack trace
  3 [main] python 5292 fork: child 6768 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
/home/user/node/wscript:228: error: could not configure a cxx compiler!
```

I did a rebaseall on cygwin and ran configure again and got these errors:

```
$ ./configure
Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib
Checking for g++                         : ok
Checking for program gcc or cc           : /usr/bin/gcc
  2 [main] python 6100 C:\cygwin\bin\python.exe: *** fatal error - unable to remap \\?\C:\cygwin\lib\python2.6\lib-dynload\_functools.dll to same address as parent: 0x3A0000 != 0x3D0000
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
002891E8  6102796B  (002891E8, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
002894D8  6102796B  (6117EC60, 00008000, 00000000, 61180977)
0028A508  61004F1B  (611A7FAC, 6124976C, 003A0000, 003D0000)
End of stack trace
  2 [main] python 4424 fork: child 6100 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
/home/user/node/wscript:230: error: could not configure a c compiler!
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the steps on this page:
http://www.garethhunt.com/2008/02/11/cygwin-died-waiting-for-dll-loading/

it worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid installing node.js through Cygwin and try to use [native Windows executable](http://nodejs.org/#download)  which [would/should](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/06/23/porting-node-to-windows-with-microsoft%E2%80%99s-help/) be preffered (unless you have some specific reasons to do otherwise).

Comment: can't install npm without curl without i need cygwin for which i also need node.js installed for